# Fetching data in Preview: "A fetch request must have an entity UncaughtExceptionError"

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a ListView file which can build the preview code fine without the Core Data piece in it.  However, when I build that ListView in the ContentView, I got an error that is not shown in the text editor like usual but in the diagnostics window. The error is "A fetch request must have an entity UncaughtExceptionError: [AppName] crashed due to an uncaught exception".

When I run the app in the simulator, the ContentView seems to build fine. (the functions attached to `Text("+")` don't work either, something about "map table argument is NULL", but one error at a time.)

EDIT: The entities in Core Data are set up as “Class Definition”.

Many many thanks in advance.

[image]

```
struct ListView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var targets: FetchedResults<TargetEntity>
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var positives: FetchedResults<PositiveEntity>
   
var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                    Text("+")
                        .onAppear{add()}
                        .onTapGesture (count: 2){
                            do {
                                print("error")
                                increment(targets.first!)
                                try viewContext.save()
                            } catch {
                                print("error")
                            }
                        }
                        .onLongPressGesture {
                            addPositive()
                        }
                
                List{
                    ForEach(positives) { item in
                        Text(item.title ?? "Unknown Title")
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    func add() {
        let countnum = TargetEntity(context: viewContext)
        countnum.countnum = 0
        save()
    }

    func addPositive(){
        let newPositive = PositiveEntity(context: viewContext)
        newPositive.title = "Action"
        save()
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
         withAnimation {
             offsets.map { positives[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
             do {
                 try viewContext.save()
             } catch {
                 let nsError = error as NSError
                 fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
             }
         }
     }

    func save() {
        do { try viewContext.save() } catch { print(error) }
    }

}

struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
          ListView()//.environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are the entities set up with regard to `Codegen`?

Comment: @Yrb They are all set as "Class Definition".  (Thank you for your help again.)

Comment: Why have you commented out `.environment(...)` for the preview code?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson When I leave it in, the preview for the ListView file won't run.

Comment: Then perhaps the problem is within your PersistenceController

Comment: When is created the persistent store? When is create the context?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I checked the "use core data" box when I create the project. I may remembered it wrong, but I don't think I changed anything in the stock persistence file.  So this really stumped me.

Comment: @Larme if you are referring to the persistence file, I am using the default one provided by XCode.

Comment: You haven’t told us what the error is when you do use `.environment(…)` which is important since you need it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry for that, I am completely stumped.  The error is now changed to something else for some reason.  "cannot use instance member 'targets' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" https://imgur.com/a/QqZAaP9   The error is not shown in the text editor section (see scroll bar) but in the diagnostic view.

Comment: I don’t see the code that could cause that error in your question. Search for "targets" in your project to find the reason for this error

Answer (score 3):

**My guess is that one of your `@FetchRequest`s are not returning any entities.**

Normally this is ok. And when you run the app, it's ok. But Preview crashes for some reason and I believe this is a bug.

You can even reproduce this bug by creating a new SwiftUI app and selecting Core Data (checkbox).

If you go into the Persistence.swift file and comment out their mock data generation (lines 11-21). Their preview for ContentView will also crash, just like yours did.

I opened up a Feedback for this to tell Apple about the problem (FB: FB12008143)

## Workaround

As a test, add some mock data so something is returned from both fetch requests. This works for me (though it's not ideal all the time).

Answer (score 0):

Just faced same issue after updating core data model with new entity, in a project created with core data.
Error happens only to "canvas" preview, with simulator or real devices everything is ok.

Issue resolved for me by adding mock of created model to `PersistenceController` under the `preview` var

Answer (score 0):

Just run into this issue with Xcode 14.3.1.
Solved by adding an entity var (user) to preview.

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    
    var user = User(context: PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    
    ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
}
```

}